# Find matrix position by requirements

Tags: algorithm, matrix, diagram

I have a question about a matrix.

There is a matrix and a list of segments.
Every segment has a name, a start or end point and a value that descrips if the start and end point refers to rows or colums of the matrix.

There can be more than one segments with the same name (but with differet start and end points).

Now we have a list of names (a , b , c).

The task is to find every matrix position (x,y) where the position fits 
 into the range (start and end point) of every segment with a name of the list.

What is the fastes way to do this?

---

I need this to finde the position of a logic expression in a KV-Diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the intervals with the same name are not overlapping then it is pretty easy to come up with an algorithm with complexity O(r * c * n). r = #rows, c = #columns and n = #names.

1. Initialize an r*c count matrix with 0s.
2. For each name...
3. For each interval with name ...
4. Increase all values of the count matrix which are inside the interval by 1.
5. Iterate over the count matrix and return all the cells where count == n.

If the intervals with the same name are not overlapping then you have to increase at most r * c values per name n, so the complexity is O(r * c * n), the + r * c in the last step don't matter.

Comment: You can speed this up, potentially a lot, by first "compressing" adjacent identically-occupied rows, and similarly for columns.  This can be done in O(m log m) time by sorting the vertical endpoints of all segments, then doing the same (with horizontal endpoints) for columns, to leave a matrix that is now at most of size at most 2m by 2m, if m is the number of segments.  (Since each name can describe many segments, I think you also need an "m" in your algorithm's time complexity.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker It is not tht easy because you have to do it for each column and each row, there is an additional dimension to the interval. The number of segments doesn't matter if the segments with the same name are not overlapping, this means max r*c segments per name, but then each one covers only one cell.

Comment: You're right about the non-overlapping names meaning you don't need m in your time complexity, sorry.  Maybe I didn't explain it very well, but compressing horizontal intervals of identical columns and vertical intervals of identical rows will indeed allow you to get rid of r and c -- for each such compressed interval, you can record the original size (number of rows or columns), so now each cell in the matrix corresponds to a *rectangle* from the original matrix (all of whose cells would receive the same count by your algorithm).